# What is wrong with array(2:)(::2) in fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, slice, fortran2008

I am learning Fortran08 and am puzzled as to why I cannot execute the following

```
integer :: array(8)
READ(*, *) array
array(2:)(::2)
```

, but the following works fine

```
integer :: array(8)
integer :: temp(7)
READ(*, *) array
temp = array(2:)
temp(::2)
```

Comment: And what would you want the `array(2:)(::2)` to mean? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple, but I don't know if that much useful. It simply is not legal Fortran syntax.

Why is it so? Because the standard says so. And why? Because the committee designed it that way. Why? You have to ask them, but note that there may be a clash with [string array indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069808/extract-substring-of-fortran-string-array).

Fortran simply does not use consecutive array indexing parentheses, unlike C. The array syntax of Fortran and C is very different in multiple aspects.

Doesn't `array(2::2)` achieve what you need?

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning fortran, I didnt know I could do (2::2).